# Конфигурирование маршрутов ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу обрабатывать маршруты, поступающие от браузера пользователя, не регистрируя никаких маршрутов в Application_Start файла Global.asax?
2. Я использую MVC 5 в текущем проекте и в методе RegisterRoutes есть такая строка:`routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`
   Не нахожу у себя в проекте файлов с расширением axd. Для чего эта строка, и в каких случаях без неё нельзя обойтись?

Comment: Стоило задать два отдельных вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Обрабатывать скорее всего запросы без маршрутизации? Маршруты - это шаблоны, которые определяются в `RegisterRoutes`. Можно создать файл с именем, которое является по умолчанию в `IIS` для запросов, неуказывающие на имя файла. Например, *default.aspx*. Но зачем это Вам? Зачем тогда *MVC*? Весь смысл *MVC* теряется.
2. *.axd - таких файлов не существует, это всего лишь имена, под которыми зарегистрировались HTTP-обработчики (**trace.axd**, **WebResource.axd** и др.).
   Строка нужна для того, чтобы запросы к таким URL (обращенные к *.axd)  не участвовали в маршрутизации, а обрабатывались как нормальные запросы, в данном случае: своими обработчиками. Если не игнорировать такие запросы, то система маршрутизации, постарается их обработать и сопоставлять значения сегментов контроллерам, их методам действия и т.д.

Например, пусть у нас имеется один единственный маршрут. Также есть игнорирование *.axd, т.е. начальный код при пустом шаблоне MVC из студии:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Уберем игнорирование и обратимся к **trace.axd**. В результате мы увидим:
[image: Без игнорирования]

Система маршрутизации пытается найти нужный контроллер. А его нет, поэтому видим такую ошибку.
Теперь вернем игнорирование и опять обратимся к **trace.axd**:
[image: С игнорированием]

Запрос был обработан нужным обработчиком, и результат этого обработчика мы увидели выше: трассировка у меня выключена, поэтому обработчик говорит, чтобы я ее включил через **web.config**.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так же использовать атрибуты маршрутизации:

```
[Route("{id:int}/{name}")]
public string Test(int id, string name)
{
    return id.ToString() + ". " + name;
}
```

http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/6.7.php